# How to download EPUBs from Calibre with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, epub, calibre

Straightforward way is not working.

I have installed `Calibre` on my Ubuntu server and loaded 1 book to it. Initially it was `FB2` format, but `Calibre` was able to convert it to `EPUB`.

Now I AM ABLE to browse to my server from any desktop computer and download EPUB from it.

But I can't do it from iPhone.

First of all they said to use `Stanza` application for it. Unfortunately, no `Stanza` application exist in `App Store`.

Also they say to use `iBooks` application and web browser. I have `iBooks` but neither webbrowser can download it. Chrome says `Error 102`, and Mercury just blinks and does nothing.

Does Apple banned downloading of EPUBs?

**UPDATE**

In `Marvin` I pressed `Get Books`, `calibre` and it shows me

[image]

and nothing else. I can press `Disconnect` if I wish. Calibre server is running on Ubuntu in LAN.

Answer (score 1):

A little googling for [`stanza ios`](https://www.google.com/search?q=stanza%20ios&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&gws_rd=ssl) brought up "Farewell, Stanza. Hello, Marvin! | Emptybottle.org" which references an app called "Marvin", which sublines itself with "Your books, everywhere.
Dropbox. iTunes. Web. OPDS. calibre." See http://marvinapp.com/

In general: Not all files are allowed to be downloaded to IOS via Safari (mainly because you have no real download-folder where all the crap you download lies until eternity; followed by the fact that you would need an app to view the stuff you downloaded and most relevant apps download 'their' stuff on their own; followed by the fact that apple wants you to use itunes to sync your digital goods which would put them into the appropriate places). That said: I toyed around with IOS8 and downloaded an .epub from a Webserver via Safari and now Safari asks me if I want to open the .epub in iBooks. And this works.

So, the answer to your "Does apple ban downloading of EPUBS?" question is "No".

Comment: Tried `Marvin` bun insuccess. see my update.

Comment: @Dims I use Marvin and dowload EPUBs from my Dropbox app.  Works perfectly.  I store my Calibre library on Dropbox, which gives me access to all my books anywhere.